# EF 6.0: Design Pattern for product table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns

I need some inputs in deciding design pattern for EF classes the below scenario:

Table: Person_Profession

Professional Types: Lawyer, Doctor, Mechanic,...

The table Person_Profession, will hold the information for an individual and its professional, each record would be differentiated by a reference table holding the professional_type.

I want to create individual domain classes for each of these professional. But certainly do not want to repeat the code.

Comment: See TPH: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618292.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank you.. looking into it.